# Is there a way to host HTML within hybris 6.7?

Tags: html, sap-commerce-cloud, headless

I have setup a custom storefront for my hybris project.
I have added a react project(package.json is the custom storefront's folder) within WEB-INF folder.

Using webpack to bundle and code split my js and css.
Is there a way to host the HTML file within Hybris 6.7?

P.S - can't do a separate frontend project, hence this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for, but you can create a new extension with a web module. This web module can have a page.

See Extension Modules: https://help.sap.com/viewer/b490bb4e85bc42a7aa09d513d0bcb18e/6.7.0.0/en-US/3a3b92d4900b4b3685157b806a73eab2.html